# Why does the 3D movie I just watched stutter?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, 3d, projection

We just watched "Captain America: Civil War" in the theatre. It was 3D and it was one of the technically worst shows I have experienced. The movie was stuttering all the time during action scenes. I think it was probably the same in scenes with less action, but not noticeable because there was much less motion.

I know quite a little bit about frame rates, projection techniques, polarization versus shutter or interference filters etc etc. However I am really wondering if this was a bad copy, bad projector setup or what. I asked the clerks and they said it's all fine and the show was the same the day before.

The best way to describe what I saw: It seemed that the frames per second was way too low. More like 10-15, instead of 24-25 and definitely not the 48/50 I have seen in the Tolkien movies. Also, it seemed that I could see the last frame and the next at the same time, or at least notice it very clearly. This lead to the stuttering sensation as well. All in all it was terrible to watch.

So does anyone know why something like this might happen? Has anyone else seen the movie and experienced the same problem, or was this a problem with this theatre?

Comment: Do you know what equipment was used, or at least whether it was film or digital?

Comment: Glass wearer and colorblind male here, I still watch movies in 3D but I do notice a lot of stutter in scenes where there is a lot going on. I got used to it, I assume for this movie it's even worse, I'll try to notice this week-end and see if it's worse of not. EDIT: Was it in 3D or Imax 3D ?

Comment: Considering it doesn't release for about a week in the US... I think most people won't have seen it.

Comment: It was digital 3D. No IMAX. And yes, it was not in the US, but in Germany.

Comment: I saw the non-3D version and it also stuttered

Comment: I saw the 2D version on release day at a midnight showing in the UK, and it seemed absolutely fine.

Comment: I just watched the 3D version in Mexico, it stuttered like crazy and was very noticeable during action scenes. Drove me nuts to the edge of wanting to get out of the room. Asked many friends about it, and they agree there was something off with the film, they all saw it in another place though.

Comment: There were moments in the 2d version where I felt some bits had had their FPS resampled, i.e. the footage of Downey Jr.'s face versus his body or other composite shots.

Comment: I just saw the Imax 3d version and I would agree whole-heartedly. I thought the projector might have been screwed up because most of the action scenes were a jumbled mess of color blocks. I almost always watch Marvel movies in this format and this was the worst presentation by far

Comment: I saw this in Imax 3D and it was exactly add you guys describe it. Extremely jarring in action scenes. I actually got up to complain about it and the staff had no idea what I was talking about. Never experienced this before watching Civil War

Comment: @Catija: "Most people" do not live in the USA.